# Some fonts in my Java-swing application look pixelized on remote desktop

Tags: java, swing, fonts, remote-desktop, synth

I'm changing the look and feel of a Java application using Synth. The font in the app used to be "Ariel" and so we wanted to change it to something else. I need a font with multi-language support, so I tried "Roboto" and "Noto". It works fine until I try to view the application from a remote desktop connection. Then it the letters get pixelized as:
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]

Instead of:
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]

Some notes:

1. I tried the "ClearType" enable and configurations. No luck.
2. When I return to the original desktop (The one I've connected to through  "remote desktop"), the view is still corrupted. If I refresh the view of the app (using `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(....)` the fonts return to look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that remote desktop sessions will disable font smoothing (anti-aliasing) as default to save bandwidth:
https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/817